# Power spectrum plot from numpy data set by using healpy

Tags: python, numpy, healpy

I am just starting to use healpy in python. In shortly, I have a data of position let

```
x = np.array([7.47098722,  7.47805867,  7.47098779....12.57804461, 12.5809734])

y = np.array([58.32516929, 58.33223959, 58.33516828, ..., 63.41415155, 63.41707922])
```

where phi(x, y) is the potential of the matter at these location. Now, I want to calculate the power spectrum for this. But I don't understand how to set my data for `healpy` to make a map by using `mollview` and calculating the power spectrum by using `anafast`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the thetas and phis to pixel indices using one of 
   `healpy`'s pixel functions,   `healpy.pixelfunc.ang2pix`. You can read more about it from https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.pixelfunc.ang2pix.html

After you have indices, you also have potential values for those indices, in other words, you have the corresponding HEALPix map(use    `mollview` to get a 
   `mollview` projection of this map). Finally, use healpy's    `anafast`, https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/healpy_spht.htm and you have you power spectrum.

For more information about    `healpy`, kindly refer- 
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/healpy/1.8.6/healpy.pdf

https://healpix.sourceforge.io/
also, visit https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov